# RecyclerView multiple selection deselects the wrong ViewHolders

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my `ViewHolder` class I have added a boolean property called `isOptionSelected`. Basically, what this property does, is control whether a `ViewHolder` is selected or not. I have made it so, that all the options are selected by default.

In my `OnBindViewHolder()` method I have an `onClickListener()` for the ViewHolder.itemView (which detects any clicks and calls an interface method called `OnItemClick()`):

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Set the text for the itemOption
        val optionString = itemOptions[position]
        holder.itemOption.text = optionString

        // Set the click listener on the view of the holder and send its position
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            clickListener.onItemClick(position, it)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        if (holder.isOptionSelected) {
            properties[position] = itemOptions[position]
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(activity.resources.getColor(R.color.popup_window_background))
        } else {
            properties[position] = ""
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(activity.resources.getColor(R.color.icons))
        }
    }
```

This is my `OnItemClicked` interface:

```
// Interface to use on the main activity to detect clicks
interface OnItemClicked {
    fun onItemClick(position: Int, view: View)
}
```

This is the `OnItemClick()` method on the `MainActivity`:

```
override fun onItemClick(position: Int, view: View) {
    val vh = menuItemRecyclerView.getChildViewHolder(view) as MeridesAndSaladsAdapter.ViewHolder
    // Invert the boolean value that the vh item holds
    vh.isOptionSelected = !vh.isOptionSelected
}
```

And this is my `ViewHolder` class:

```
class ViewHolder(itemView: View?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var itemOption: TextView = itemView!!.findViewById(R.id.meridesAndSaladsOption)
    // All options are selected by default
    var isOptionSelected: Boolean = true
}
```

The problem is that when I am clicking on a `ViewHolder.itemView` the view that gets deselected is 1-2 rows above what I am tapping. After I deselect some rows and then try to select some of the deselected rows, the selections are, seemingly, random. What's more, sometimes when I deselect or select something, some extra rows get changed as well.

Is there something I am missing? Or am I doing something horribly wrong?

Comment: Do you ever call `notifyItemInserted()`, `notifyItemRemoved()`, or any other `notifyXYZ` methods that **aren't** just `notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: The only notifyXYZ method that I call is the one you can see, i.e .`notifyDataSetChanged()`. @BenP.

Comment: Ah. Then my answer will probably not solve your problem. But it's still good to know about.

Comment: I thought that since I know my rows wouldn't change position I could just use the `position` provided by `onBindViewHolder()` but I guess that was a wrong assumption. I also changed `notifyDataSetChanged()` to `notifyItemChanged(holder.adapterPosition)` and that seems to solve the problem partially. Now the rows get deselected then reselected and if I tap them a second time they work as expected... The rows seem to only work on the second tap for now... Any idea what that might be? Thank you for the great input @BenP.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ViewHolders get reused and will have their isOptionsSelected value reset to the default value (True) when this happens.  You need to store whether items are selected or not outside the ViewHolder class and get/load the value in your onBindViewHolder, probably store the value as part of the itemOptions objects.  Also, need to toggle the value of those objects (rather than the viewholder) from your onClickListeners.

Comment: It seems like this is the correct answer. All information about an item, including whether or not it is selected, should be stored with the _item_, not with the ViewHolder. ViewHolders will be re-used for different items, so you'll run into trouble if a "selected" view holder is reused for an "unselected" item.

Comment: So you suggest I create an array that holds a boolean value for each `ViewHolder` in my `RecyclerView.Adapter` and change that instead?

Comment: Basically yes.  I normally have an array of objects, each object holds all values a viewholder needs to setup the UI and the adapter does the work of updating the viewholders with the corresponding objects.  I normally store the object array where ever the adapter is stored but you should be able to store it in the adapter itself and get it to work too.  If the object array values change, you call the adapters update method with the array and then notifyDataSetChanged() or preferably notifyItemChanged() if only a single data object changed and you know the position (you do).

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on the fact that you're doing something I know you're not supposed to do. It's possible that fixing this won't solve your issue, but it's still worth pointing out:

The `position` argument to `onBindViewHolder()` should not be considered to be `final`. In other words, a view holder's position can change over time.

Your posted code includes this:

> ```
> holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
>     clickListener.onItemClick(position, it)
>     notifyDataSetChanged()
> }
> ```

Imagine your view holder is initially bound for position `14`, and you then insert two rows at the beginning of the list. Your click listener will still call `onItemClick(14, it)`, but your *real* position is now `16`.

You can solve this by using the the `getAdapterPosition()` method on `ViewHolder`. This will give you the live position instead of just the initial position:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
    clickListener.onItemClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), it)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

For more info, see this Google IO presentation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LqBlYJTfLP4&feature=youtu.be&t=43m10s (timestamped to 43:10, where they talk about this `position` problem).